# Spring Boot Runtime Property Changes After Deploying Start of Application

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, configuration, executable-jar

I came across a requirement of switch on/off case in Spring Boot Application. We have a notification service implemented which is working on property : 
notifyall = true  in application.properties file.

Now I want to stop the notification services by specifying notifyall = false in application.properties file without any downtime.

Is it possible in Spring Boot Application?

If yes, then any step wise approach or relevant tutorial will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use spring boot actuators.

Please go through the following link: https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_environment_changes

it mentions @ConfigurationProperties with prefix; any change in the configuration will be loaded automatically.